# Is it possible to send Server less email in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, email

Hi there I am trying to send server less email through react native I have researched about it and came to know that it is possible to send in Reactjs using EMAILJS but in react-native I have not found any solution yet. Can anyone help in this scenario ? or guide me about any available library. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmailJS supports [REST APIs](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/). You can directly call them from your React Native app without any 3rd party library.

```
const sendMail = async () => {
  const url = 'https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send';

  const data = {
    service_id: 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID',
    // other data .....
  };
  
  const params = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  
  try {
    await fetch(url, params);
    console.log('Your mail is sent!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dear. It does print email sent in console but i am not receiving email and neither my service sent items shows an sent notification

Answer (score 1):

I was not receiving the email either, but make sure to check out Account/Security to make sure "Allow EmailJS API for non-browser applications" is checked. Also I included my private key per EmailJS's recommendations.

Here is the initial code I got to work using axios:

```
const sendEmail = async () => {
  try {
      const payload = {
          service_id: 'SERVICE_ID',
          template_id: 'TEMPLATE_ID',
          user_id: 'PUBLIC_KEY', //this includes a dash that is part of my key
          accessToken: 'PRIVATE_KEY',
          template_params: {
              from_name: 'James',
              to_name: 'David',
              message: 'Test 123'
          }
      };
      const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
      const { status } = await axios.post('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send', payload, { headers });
      if(status === 200) {
          console.log('success');
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('error in axios Post-->', error);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to open the default email client with prepopulated data from your application using https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail for example.